# how do i search an address form a group of columns from a table (zip,state,country)?

Tags: sql, mysql

scenarioi:-
1) User enters an address into a search field. Address maybe zip,state or country

2) Now i have to take that address which may be in any order or which may just contain the country, state or zip and check the database if the the results exists or not.

Any advice on this topic would be awesome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like :

```
split address on space
```

build where clause as

```
WHERE zip||state||country like '%address_part_one%'
   OR zip||state||country like '%address_part_two%'
and so on ...
```

If you have fulltext enabled for the three fields :

```
WHERE MATCH (zip,state,country) AGAINST ('address_part_one')
   OR MATCH (zip,state,country) AGAINST ('address_part_two')
...
```

Comment: can i do this type of search with full text support ?

Comment: can full text search be enabled on views?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to create an index on a view in MySQL. But may be i am wrong. Have a look at the doc.

Answer (score 1):

How about this one?

```
'SELECT * FROM table WHERE address LIKE \''. addslashes($search) .'\'
  OR zip = '. (int)$search .'
  OR country LIKE \''. addslashes($search) .'\''
```

Comment: i think this will be slow once the databae accumulates large volumes of data.

was looking for something like a FULL TEXT SEARCH solution